# Переименование колонки приводит к ошибке

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Переименовываю колонку в `DataFrame` для того, чтобы сделать код более универсальным. При попытке обратиться к `DataFrame` по новому имени возникает ошибка.

Почему так?

Так выглядит `df` до переименования:

```py
   budj.head()
```

```
timestamp_day   client_pin
   2019-06-04       XAUWBG  
   2019-06-04       XAVPXW  
   2019-06-04       XADFZA  
   2019-06-04       XAC5GF  
   2019-06-04       XAOD2P
```

```py
    budj.columns._data[1] = 'XPIN'
    budj.head()
```

```
timestamp_day      XPIN 
   2019-06-04    XAUWBG  
   2019-06-04    XAVPXW  
   2019-06-04    XADFZA  
   2019-06-04    XAC5GF  
   2019-06-04    XAOD2P  

budj[['XPIN']]
```

Приводит к ошибке:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['XPIN'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Извиините, а что такое "vipis.head()"?

Comment: Оу, sorry, это опечатка, имелось в виду конечно budj.head()

Comment: Замените пожалуйста картинки кодом и данными как текст. Тогда было бы легко опечатку исправить, да и данные можно было бы копировать. Вопросы с картинками плохо оцениваютя на этом сайте.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание- поправил. Могу заметить, что оформлять данные не слишком удобно. Если просто скопировать таблицу из клипборда в тегах html, то переносы строк не подхватываются, а в виде отдельного html блока некрасиво. А так было бы здорово если можно было бы просто при помощи `budj.head().to_clipboard()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что вы делаете - это неподдерживаемый "грязный хак", поэтому вы и получаете `KeyError`.

**NOTE:** использовать, а тем более изменять *внутренние* (начинающиеся с подчеркивания) и недокументированные переменные классов / объектов никогда не стоит. Даже если это работает с текущей версией модуля, это легко может "сломаться" в последующих версиях. Т.к. это внутренняя переменная, а не часть API - разроботчики модуля могут ее удалить / переименовать / etc.

Переименование столбцов в Pandas делается так:

```
budj = budj.rename(columns={"userId":"XPIN"})
```

если переименовывать нужно по индексу столбца, а не по наименованию:

```
budj = budj.rename(columns={budj.columns[1]:"XPIN"})
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо, так всё корректно работает. Короткая форма написания не всегда самая лучшая